# Why is putting an '&' before a giving me the result I want?

Tags: c, string, printing

I am just getting started with C and don't really understand how a few things work. I wanted to make a program which took input of a string and printed it as it is.
This is the program I wrote:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

My first issue with this is that there is no output whatsoever. Not even the first character which i expected to get.
Secondly, when I put a '&' before the print statement variable it works just fine i.e. prints the entire string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("%s",&a);
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're second example my *seem to work* but in fact you're invoking Undefined Behaviour so anything might happen.

In detail:

1. You have a single `char a` and you call `scanf("%s",&a)`; But here `scanf()` will copy the entire NUL terminated string into the address you pass so even if you only type one single character scanf will copy that character into a and the `'\0'` into `&a + 1` what invokes Undefined behaviour, so your program might crash, overwrite other variables or .... If you want to scan an entire string you have to define an array like `char s[1024];` and call `scanf("%s,s)`. If you want to scan a single character, call `scanf("%c",&a);`
2. linke in `scanf()`, `printf("%s",...)` is used to print an entire string and therefore expects a `char *` parameter. That's why it didn't print anything in the first example (in fact it's Undefined Behaviour again). To print a single character, call `printf("%c",a);`

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

1. The `char` type stores a *single* character, not a string.  To store a string, you need to set aside an *array* of `char`:

   ```
   char a[20]; // stores a string up to 19 characters long
   ```

   In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued *terminator*.  Strings are stored in arrays of character type.  Because of that terminator, you need an array that's *at least* N+1 elements wide in order to store a string that's N characters long.

   The `%s` conversion specifier for both `printf` and `scanf` expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *`, not `char` - it's expecting the *address* of the first element of an *array* of `char`.

   Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.

Putting all of that together, you need to make the following changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 20
#define EXPAND(x) #x            // I'll explain this in more detail below
#define STR(x) EXPAND(x)
#define LENGTH_FMT STR(LENGTH)

int main( void )
{
  char a[LENGTH+1];
  scanf( "%" LENGTH_FMT "s", a );
  printf( "%s\n", a );
  return 0;
}
```

The `%s` conversion specifier, by itself, doesn't know how big the target array is, and will write past the end of it if you enter more data than the array is sized to hold.  You can pass an optional field width that tells `scanf` to read no more than so many characters into the array, but unlike `printf`, you can't pass it as an argument - you have to hardcode it as part of the format.

Since we're using a preprocessor macro to define the size of the array, we use some additional preprocessor magic to add that size to the format specifier.  It's a multi-step process because of how the preprocessor works, but it basically goes like this:

```
"%" LENGTH_FMT "s"
```

expands to

```
"%" STR(LENGTH) "%s"
```

which expands to

```
"%" EXPAND(20) "%s"
```

which expands to

```
"%" #20 "s"
```

which expands to

```
"%" "20" "s"
```

which is finally concatenated into

```
"%20s"
```

so we're calling `scanf` as

```
scanf( "%20s", a );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read in the `char` type the correct format specifier is `%c` and not `%s`.

Comment: I wanted to read a string and then print it. That is why I used %s. Why is putting & in printf statement printing the string whereas not putting it doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

In C every variable has its own address. When we want to read something, we send the address respectively (and we use `&` to get address from variable).

The reason is, `scanf()` needs to modify values of a and b and but they are local to scanf().

So in order to reflect changes in the variable a and b of the main function, we need to pass addresses of them. We cannot simply pass them by value.

Exemple:

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

But, in case of `printf()` function as we are only going to print the values of the variables in output console, there are no changes going to be made in variable a and b’s values. So it is not required to send their addresses.

Exemple of printf():

```
printf("%d %d", a, b);
```

(Also, if you wand to scan char you must use %c instead of %s)

Comment: But if i don't use & in printf() it doesn't give any output. Whereas if i use & it prints it perfectly why does this happen?

Comment: We don't have `string` type of data in C. `char` can save only one symbol. When you scan with `%s` scanf() read all world (to the first space) and save in memory. But only the first character is stored in the variable. You should use array to save string (string is just an array of chars). First of all you must create `char array[100]` and then you can save string to it (remember, there must be a `'\0'`  at the end of the string). Then you can use `gets` or `fgets` to read and save string. Exemple: `fgets(array, 100, stdin);`.

Comment: Where `array` is the name of your array,  `100` - the maximum number of elements that can be saves, end `stdin` - input stream. Read more about fgets you can [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/)